# Drawing gradient of sector of circle on canvas in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, canvas, drawing, gdi+, delphi-7

I drawing a circular progress control in Delphi 7 and I have a problem. How I should draw sector of the circle with gradient of two colors (one color starts and another ends)? I use the pie function for draw a circle sector.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks, Serge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a starting point (the approach is not universal): you could take a ready-made gradiented circle image and draw a sector with `TCanvas.Pie` over it.

The sector should be centered the same as the circle, of course, and its color is supposed to be the same as the background color, so effectively you will be hiding part of the circle, leaving a gradiented sector visible.

Of course, it will not work out for an arbitrary background...

Comment: Thanks, your post helped me find a solution :)